# toggleSlide issue on Chrome - cutting letters / invisible text

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I'm using jquery 1.8.2 and toggleSlide animation to smootly show search input box but that have two issues on chrome - one of them I've separated into [a jsfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/nilphilus/MUvz5/)

```
$('#hiddenBlock').slideToggle(500);
$('#inputHiddenBlock').slideToggle(500);
$('#but').slideToggle(500);
```

On chrome open [this fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/nilphilus/MUvz5/) and click button - write some text in the textbox and click button again twice - one to hide second to show again - text is now invisible and stay that way until get refreshed by f.e. writing one more letter.

This maybe also connected to second issue, which is seems connected to canvas/displaying text - it allow cut letters like 'l' in half....

In that example you see 'l' and 't':
['l' and 't' http://img171.imageshack.us/img171/5784/beztytuuvxq.png](http://img171.imageshack.us/img171/5784/beztytuuvxq.png)

Comment: Unable to replicate this issue

Comment: i m not seeing any text i or t to be cutted on typing.
i also didn't got your first issue.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You don't need to `slideToggle` both the textbox and search button. Just the div `hiddenBlock` is enough.

I simplyfied your solution:

```
// on dom ready hides your div
$(document).ready(function(){
  $('#hiddenBlock').hide();
});

 function toggleSearchWindow() {
   $('#hiddenBlock').slideToggle("fast");
 }

 $('input[type=button]').click(function() {
   toggleSearchWindow();
 });​
```

[**TEST**](http://jsfiddle.net/MUvz5/12/)

**UPDATE** I put the typed text in a temp variable to see whether this solve your cutted text:

**[TEST2](http://jsfiddle.net/MUvz5/13/)**

Comment: I know about it - it just look a bit prettier that way - but if this is the only solution I'll go that way

Comment: and unfortunetly that broke my second issue more... but it is also connected to page layout it seems and I fail with separate it to jsfiddle...

Comment: You might include more code so that we can see why your text is cutted because I can see that in this jsfiddle.

Comment: checked, not exactly solved second problem but give me a hint. I've back to slideToggle on input and button but changed time to 650.

Answer (score 1):

Try removing

```
display:none;
```

from #inputhiddenblock and #but css and then remove

```
$('#inputHiddenBlock').slideToggle(500);
$('#but').slideToggle(500);
```

Answer (score 0):

I have update your jsfiddle link.

Problem was you are not initialize the input-text field and in dom load for input-text field we have initialize as inline not display none.

I have commented it;

> $('#inputHiddenBlock').slideToggle(500);